# (Solved) How can i solved: Deprecated syntax, please prepend 'hardware_interface/'?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone.

I am trying to display my model robot in gazebo and get this warning:

Deprecated syntax, please prepend 'hardware_interface/' to 'PositionJointInterface' within the  tag in joint 'joint_base'.

I know it's not important but I want to solve it.

This is my code in the xacro file of the transmission block:

<xacro:macro name="transmission_block" params="joint_name">

```
  <transmission name="tran1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="${joint_name}">
      <hardwareInterface>PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor1">          
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
```

</xacro:macro>

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16223/(solved)-how-can-i-solved:-deprecated-syntax,-please-prepend-%27hardware_interface/%27-?/) by [Daniel Tobon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3221/daniel-tobon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lejan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46975/lejan/) on 2021-05-06**:
Hi, I have the same warning, but when I append "hardware_interfase/" I receive this:

No matching hardware interface found for 'hardware_interfase/EffortJointInterface' while loading interfaces for pitch_joint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As you said, it is just a warning and doesn't break anything. To stop the message, simply follow the warning message to get:

```
<hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
```

---

Originally posted by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3232/hamzamerzic/) with karma: 40 on 2017-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Tobon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3221/daniel-tobon/) on 2017-05-23**:
thaaank you!!

**Comment by [Mav14](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2678/mav14/) on 2017-11-08**:
I have a related issue. My transmission is set up as

```
 
    transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission
    
      EffortJointInterface
    
    
      EffortJointInterface
      1
```

**Comment by [Mav14](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2678/mav14/) on 2017-11-08**:
And this is the error I get `Could not find resource 'waist' in 'hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface'.`. I can't figure out what's causing that despite looking everywhere.